# WCF client's Open() method no longer throw exceptions after security is disabled. What to do?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service-client pair. We have been relying on calling Open() on the client's factory method to make sure that the service is available before we make any call. Something like:

```
MyClient GetClient() 
{
    MyClient client = new MyClient();
    try
    {
        client.Open();
        return client;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        //perform an (important) error-handling here
    }
}
```

In this way, the caller codes will just do something like:

```
client = factory.GetClient();
client.CallMethodInTheService();
```

and they don't need to worry about error handling.

This works when we set security mode to Windows and  clientCredentialType to Windows in the wshttpbinding. client.Open() will throw an exception when service is unavailable, so the error handling code will get executed. However, now we are deploying in an environment where we cannot use Windows credential based security, so we set security mode to none. However, this cause client.Open() no longer throws an exception when the service is unavailable, and we have some problem because we rely on this code in the catch block of the factory.

What is the reason that Open() throws an exception when we use message security but not when we disable the security?
How can we perform similar availability checking if security is set to none? I don't think it's a good solution to put a try catch with error handling on each individual call. Is there another way for the factory method to check the availability of the service before returning the client object?

Comment: Your avatar makes me want to downvote you.  Fortunately I am resisting the temptation.

Comment: why? I was hoping it would tempt people to upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception will not be thrown with any security but only in cases where a session is involved. e.g. establishSecurityContext=true or negotiateServiceCredentials=true (the defautls). In those cases before the first call to the server the client will send some infra messages to it in order to decide on a cryptogtaphic key to use. When you call open() you explicitly ask to make this negotiation now (otherwise it will happen on the first call). If you turn on Wcf logging (or Fiddler) you will see this.

When the service is not avialable the negotiation will fail so you get an exception.

Without security there is no session so no exception.

I suggest you add a IsAlive operation to the service.

Comment: cool. Thanks for the explanation and proposed solution! It seems to work, I wish there were solution without updating the code though.